# custom annotations

Tags: java, annotations

If I create a custom annotation like this:

```
public @interface TODO
{
    String msg();    
    String start_date();
}
```

then a method:

```
@TODO
(
   msg="will be developed!",
   start_date="05/01/2010"
)
public static void Calculator()
{
}
```

after I call it:

```
Calculator();
```

If I wanted that the compiler warn me about it how could I do that?

Comment: The end of your question is not very understandable... :-(

Comment: I wish that when I compile I had a warning to the compiler like it does if I put, e.g., @Deprecated or @Override annotation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question, some weeks ago. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752607/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-custom-java-compiler-warning-message/1754823#1754823) to both the question and my answer.

You can easily adapt this code to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You must write an [annotation processor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) and invoke `apt` to run it on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Annotation Processing Tool (apt)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html) to make your own AnnotationProcessor and print the message with [javax.annotation.processing.Messager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE, there are plenty of good options. For Eclipse:

- use the built-in plug-in which locates all `TODO`, `FIXME`, etc. words in your code and puts them in a special view.
- register your own custom builder which can show you the warnings

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with Java compiler?