# How does Serializable work?

Tags: java, serializable

This question is not about how to *use* `Serializable`, I already know that. However, I was wondering how implementing `Serializable` brings up the following warning:

`The serializable class MyClass does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`

Suppose I wanted to write an interface like `Serializable`, how would I go about "warning" the programmer implementing my interface to declare a variable? I've tried looking at the source code for `Serializable.java` but I couldn't find anything which would result in this behaviour. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the behavior you're looking for would be better implemented using annotations and the annotation processor. The fact that the compiler warns you about not declaring `serialVersionUID` is handled by a different mechanism at the compiler level (and therefore, out of the reach of the programmer); it's more of a coding convention enforced by the serialization API than a consequence of implementing the `Serializable` interface.

In fact, [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/Serializable.java) you can examine the source code of [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and as you can see, there's nothing special about it for forcing a compiler warning:

```
/* comments removed for brevity */
package java.io;
public interface Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think it is possible with mere Java (maybe with some annotations? not sure about it).

The fact is that the `Serializable` interface is not a normal Java interface but more a tagging element, it is used as an *interface* but it's something special, so it is handled in its own way by the compiler (as its meaning expresses a functionality, like interfaces, which is not transparently implemented in the code by default).

Comment: Yes, the Java compiler probably does something special to print that warning.  I don't think you can program anything like that yourself in Java.

Comment: `Serializable` has a lot of built-in magic in the language and compiler that you can't replicate in your average library.

Comment: I think @Jack hits all the good points. Nathan, the question is how bad do you want this? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1752607/845279) post describes a possible solution even though it seems like an awful lot of work. Please let us know if it worked.

Comment: The Java compiler does not print that warning. Some IDEs do.