# How to customize and trigger Java compilation error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I want to define and trigger some customized Java compilation errors in **Eclipse**.
Basically I want that some system calls in some methods trigger a **compilation error**.

In [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752607/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-custom-java-compiler-warning-message) an **Annotaion** based solution is proposed but it is not suitable in my case because I cannot predict when the copilation errors will happen. All I want is that when a developer makes a System Call for example a compilation error will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you look for, but consider using a custom [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) definition. Here is a sample from the checkstyle documentation that marks calls to `System.out.println` as invalid:

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <!-- . matches any character, so we need to escape it and use \. to match dots. -->
    <property name="format" value="System\.out\.println"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish something like that would be to write a plug-in for Eclipse that analyzes code during builds. But the details of doing so is really out of the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your `Builder` implementation and register it with the Java Project.

You could [start here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_an_Eclipse_builder%3F).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent developpers from using java.lang.System for example, a nice trick is to create a custom class **java.lang.System** in your projet, so every call to any methods of java.lang.System (the real one) will occure  a compilation problem.

If you use maven, you can also create the class in a seperate maven project with scope provided to not be packaged with the real application.