# How to add a compiler warning in Android Studio?

Tags: android, warnings, android-studio, compiler-warnings

In C# in Visual Studio I can do this with

```
#warning The following method needs refactoring for clarity
```

What's the Android Studio equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this: `@SuppressWarnings("your message")` for example

```
@SuppressWarnings("your message") 
myMethod(){
body;
}
```

also, look at this question:

> [How to intentionally cause a custom java compiler warning message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752607/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-custom-java-compiler-warning-message)