# How to give warning message in own API?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

Is that possible to give custom warning message in my own API like below? Is `Resource leak:'ois' is never closed` message related with Java API or JVM?

[image]

Comment: Similar to this is one I always want to give;  where two methods must be overridden together, similar to equals and hashcode

Comment: @CanMingir that one comes from the compiler. If you want a custom one, how about a custom annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752607/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-custom-java-compiler-warning-message

Comment: I think that this comes from IDE - here eclipse

Comment: Maybe you can do it with custom `Exception`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible using a compiler API. You have to extend an AbstractProcessor and then make sure compiler knows about it.

Lets say we don't like programmers to swear in the source code. So, when someone defines a field with name "shit", we want to show a warning. Here is a simple implementation:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind;

@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class Test extends AbstractProcessor {
    public int shit;
    public int foo;

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> rootElements = roundEnv.getRootElements();

        for (Element element : rootElements) {
            if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
                List<? extends Element> classElements = element.getEnclosedElements();

                for (Element classElement : classElements) {
                    if (classElement.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
                        if (classElement.getSimpleName().contentEquals("shit")) {
                            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                                Kind.WARNING,
                                "How dare you to swear in the source code?!",
                                classElement
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
    }
}
```

Now, we want to apply such a processor just for this very class, because there is an ugly bad-called field too.

Using a command line:

```
javac Test.java
javac -processor Test Test.java
```

We need to firstly build a processor and then apply it while compiling (in this case to the same file).

And this is the output we get:

```
Test.java:17: warning: How dare you to swear in the source code?!
    public int shit;
           ^
1 warning
```

To have the same warning in Eclipse or any other IDE, it's necessary to change compiler settings so it uses this custom processor.

**Update**: In the comments, kapep sent a link on how to set a custom processor in Eclipse: http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/

---

Just for the record: Exactly the same warning may be achieved by implementing interface Closeable:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test implements Closeable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

And you see the same warning:

[image]

Comment: Good updated answer, although incorporating profanities isn't particularly necessary. +1

Comment: Setting up a processor in eclipse is a bit more complicated. You need to create a jar with some meta resource and activate a few settings. Here is a tutorial: http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/ (still valid for newer versions of java)

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the JAR, but didn't know the rest of things. I updated my answer.

Comment: @tzima can you elaborate what the interface `Closeable` has to do with the answer? Why does that particular interface induce the warning? It doesn't contain the word "shit".

Answer (score 1):

You can create warnings, notes, errors and other diagnostic messages like this using an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html). It's a compiler plugin api integrated in the JDK. It lets you analyse the outline structure of source code. Despite the name you don't really need to handle any annotation when processing code. Messages are created using the [Messager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html) class. If you provide an element, it will be marked and the message will be shown next to it in the source code editor.

You won't be able to show message on elements inside methods or expressions though, only on declarations like types, properties, methods or parameters. It's possible to additionally parse the method body and generate messages based on the content using other tools, but as far as I know you can't show the message on the actual local element then. You could still show the message on the enclosing method or don't specify any element at all and show it in the IDE's log.

The IDE also needs to support this. I know that Eclipse and NetBeans do support messages generated by annotation processors, but there are probably other modern IDE that do so as well. If you need more features like messages on elements inside method bodies or the quick fix feature as shown in the example, I guess you need to create a plugin for the IDE.

Comment: @Vulcan I thought about adding some example but it seemed a bit out of scope to me as the question is quite broad, so I tried to just give an overview of what is possible. Well, now the other answer has been updated with an good example, I guess that will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that it is related to the eclipse ide, you could possibly write a plugin which  displays warnings like that.

For example, when you use a method which has the annotation '@Deprecated' the ide automatically tells the programmer that the method is deprecated.