# How JVM gives warning to add serial version id when implementing Serializable interface?

Tags: java

We know that we can create marker interface. Suppose I want to create a marker interface like `Serializable` interface.

How can I force the JVM to tell user to add serial version id as happens with the `Serializable` interface?

Can I use our own marker interface in file handling or in RMI calls instead of `Serializable` interface?

Suppose my marker interface is

```
public interface SyncBean {}
```

How can I make the JVM require adding `serial` version id for implementing classes?

Comment: It basically comes down to: "How to do any custom compile time warnings in Java" and your best bet is compile time annotations. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1754823/3020903

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it seems like the compiler warning is specific to `Serializable`. As you can see [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/Serializable.java.html), there are not special annotations or anything on `Serializable` to make it act the way it does — the behavior is hard-coded into `javac`.

What you can do (still using an interface) is this:

```
public interface SyncBean {
    long getVersionID();
}
```

Implementation would look like this:

```
public class MySyncable {
    long getVersionID() { return 142L; }
}
```

You can make these `static` in Java 8.

---

Another (better) option is to use an annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SyncBean {
    public long versionID();
}
```

Implementation looks like this:

```
@SyncBean(142L)
public class MySyncable {
}
```

Access looks like this:

```
MySyncable.class.getAnnotation(SyncBean.class).versionID();
```

Comment: i don't want to use Serializable interface.

Comment: Then unfortunately you can't get *exactly* the same behavior. `Serializable` is just special.

Comment: I added a possible workaround. Let me know what you think.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i was thinking exact behavior like Serializable.

Comment: Sorry. Another option is annotation, but yeah, the `Serializable` behavior isn't available. Good luck.